# Get all files from VSS for a given date?

Tags: visual-sourcesafe

Is there a way I can ask Visual source safe to get all the files from a given date for a project?  We don't use labels, so I can't roll back to a specific label and am hoping that I can somehow just call a certain date range to get the files as they existed on a specific date? Impossible?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As far as I know you have to use the [get](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/661w6e3d(VS.80).aspx) command at a command prompt, not the gui. Something like this should do:

```
ss Get "$/AFolder" -R -Vd15-03-2009;2:00a
```

The -R option makes the get recursive and the -vd option gets the version at the specified date.

Comment: Be sure to use the date/time format as used in the VSS database

Answer (score 2):

Using SourceSafe: Get by Date

[http://web.archive.org/web/20120615102028/http://brennan.offwhite.net/mtblog/archives/000282.htmll](http://brennan.offwhite.net/mtblog/archives/000282.html)

Comment: Looks original page is dead. Maybe this helps:http://web.archive.org/web/20120615102028/http://brennan.offwhite.net/mtblog/archives/000282.html

Answer (score 2):

You can right-click the project, choose **Show History** and get the version of a given date from the history explorer.

Comment: That only works if a change was made on the particular date and time that you are interested in.  If you want to grab a snapshot from between checkins, you have to use the command-line.

Answer (score 1):

Using the command line, use the `get` command with the `-Vd` parameter

`ss get $/Project -R -GTU -Vd4/30/2009;3:00a`

I'm not sure, but I don't think there is a way to do this with the ui.

Comment: You can use this format in the 'get' dialog box too. Enter "d15-03-2009" in the label field. It can be confusing though as you don't get an error message if the date format is wrong (it just doesn't update the files.)

Comment: I know you can use a date in the Show History dialog, but at least in VSS 2005, there is only a "Get Latest" that I can find, and it does not have any label field.

Comment: See Robert Harvey's post for more details http://web.archive.org/web/20120615102028/http://brennan.offwhite.net/mtblog/archives/000282.html