# How to get complete project by date in Source Safe?

Tags: visual-sourcesafe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get all files from VSS for a given date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911426/get-all-files-from-vss-for-a-given-date)

I need to get a complete project recursively as it existed on a specified date in the past. How can I do that without having to look at and selectively recover each individual file? Source Safe 8.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, it might be possible.  Here are instructions I received from a co-worker (thanks Bruce!) for doing just that with SourceSafe 6:

1. In the VSS database, select the top-most project (not an individual file in the project) that you are interested in.
2. Get the history for that project, making sure that the "Recursive" and "Include file histories" check boxes are selected. The "Include Labels" check-box is optional, but you definitely don't want "Labels only."
3. Select the file / date you're interested in from the history list box.
4. Click the "Get" button.
5. Click the "Yes" button on the pop-up dialog that asks, "Get the entire project containing this file version?"

Hope this helps (for next time).

Comment: I didn't actually get the prompt for "Get the entire project containing this file version?", but it seemed to get the entire project anyway. It'll take some time to get this back to a compilable state, but this looks like it did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If that particular version was not branched out or labelled, I believe you have no choice but to manually check and recover each file from Visual Sourcesafe.

More information on [labelling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1zy8w180(v=VS.80).aspx) and [branching and sharing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/4dw155ey(v=VS.80).aspx) for Visual Sourcesafe over at MSDN.

If you have a choice of using another SCM, I would recommend using [Visual SVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/) to integrate an SVN Server with Visual Studio.

Comment: If VisualSVN is not an opinion because it's commercial, there's always AnkhSVN.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. No, I'm afraid that labeling and/or branching was never used on this website project. Ugh, this is going to be an arduous process...

Comment: It could be really a good learning experience; When you ship your code, why not ZIP your working copy used when you built it, and place both the zip and your setup.exe on a network location, which is backed up by your corporate backup system, so it is never never lost?