# Get a VSS project tree for a specified label using the command line?

Tags: command-line, visual-sourcesafe

Similar to this question:

[Get all files from VSS for a given date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911426/get-all-files-from-vss-for-a-given-date)

I am trying to write a script that get a VSS project tree for a specified label. I have this:

```
:: Path to the SS.exe command
set ss="C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual SourceSafe\ss"

:: Path to the srcsafe.ini file for the repository
set SSDIR=\\Glopsvrfile01\VSS_Data

:: Path to the project root in VSS
set VSSRoot="$/Customers/MyCustomer/MyProject"

set /p version="Please enter a SourceSafe label: "

mkdir temp

:: vvv Here is the command vvv
%ss% get %VSSRoot% -Vl%version% -GLtemp -R

del /s /q temp\*.*
rmdir temp
```

and I am definitely passing in a valid label (V1.0.29) but it just comes back with 
  Version not found

Having tried it with a version labeled TempLabel, that works! Is it just the dots?

Does anyone know how to list all the labeled versions of a project on the command line?

-- Alistair

Answer (score 2):

After spending couple of hours, finally I able to find the small glitch in your provided script.

Simple replace  Vl with VL in the line below. Remaining is perfect.

```
%ss% get %VSSRoot% -Vl%version% -GLtemp -R
```

Enjoy!

Asif