# project_path not found when using VSS2GIT

Tags: git, visual-sourcesafe

I tried using VSS2GIT to move the source code from VSS to GIT repository.

But I am getting an error as `$/project_path` not found.
What do I need to fix?

[image: Error]

I am using git version 2.8.3.windows.1 and VSS 6.0. These are both on windows 8.1 .
Storage file for VSS is available on some virtual space.

I am getting the error just at the beginning of the migration and have not yet started anything on GIT.

Comment: What command-line do you type? What exact ouput error message do you get? What version of SourceSafe and Git are you using? On which OS? What VSS2Git are you using? (https://github.com/trevorr/vss2git?)

Comment: I am using git version 2.8.3.windows.1 and VSS 6.0. These are both on windows 8.1 .
storage file for VSS is available on some virtual space.
I tried the above link but its telling how to use it. If any error comes then they also unaware of it as this one has not been tested that much.

Comment: OK. What command-line do you type? What exact ouput error message do you get?

Comment: I Have Added the error screenshot in question. 
I am getting the error just at the beginning of the migration na d have not yet started anything on GIT.

Answer (score 3):

The plugin code resulting in a "`not found in $`" is [`Vss2Git/VssPathMapper.cs`](https://github.com/trevorr/vss2git/blob/cf6a024159da265b4a2bb479414a49035eca5740/Vss2Git/VssPathMapper.cs#L584-L593)

```
private VssProjectInfo ResolveProjectSpec(string projectSpec)
{
      if (!projectSpec.StartsWith("$/"))
      {
          throw new ArgumentException("Project spec must start with $/", "projectSpec");
      }

      foreach (var rootInfo in rootInfos.Values)
      {
          if (projectSpec.StartsWith(rootInfo.OriginalVssPath))
```

Double-check your folder/project "`Yxx11.2.1/workspace`": you should put in there the exact name (case sensitive) of a [VisualSourceSafe project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8asz4157(v=vs.80).aspx), as [described here](http://li153-236.members.linode.com/tutorials/vss/index.php):

> A VSS Database is organised as a tree structure, with each of the nodes of the tree being a VSS Project. Each database contains a single root project, which can branch (to a depth of 15 nodes) into sub-projects.
>
> VSS Projects are misleadingly named; instead they should be thought of as directly analagous to filesystem directories, being unordered collections of up to 8000 files of any type.
> To illustrate this, note that where an application's source-code is organised into files that live in subdirectories off the main directory, these subdirectories have to be mapped onto subprojects of the application's main project directory.

Comment: See also if your ss project is gettable as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/6015868/6309.

Comment: http://www.geektieguy.com/2013/11/30/migrate-visual-sourcesafe-to-git-a-short-how-to/
Thank VonC. I was going through the above link and found that guy is using some ****.root file for his project. can you tell where it can be found ?

Comment: @AnuragKumarPandey Using? He reports find .root folders when cloning the resulting git repo. I don't think he was plaaning on finding or "using" them.