# How to get latest files based on modified date from vss using ant script

Tags: ant

I wrote ant script to get latest modified files from vss.

```
<target name="prepare">
    <vssget localPath="C:\build"
            date="11/16/2011"
            recursive="true"
            login="ss,ss"
            vsspath="$\PIS" filetimestamp="modified"/>
</target>
```

If I am executing above ant script, I getting all the files from vss. I need files based on given the date. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from this source code of ***`org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.vss.MSVSSGET`*** class:

```
/**
 * Builds a command line to execute ss.
 * @return     The constructed commandline.
 */
Commandline buildCmdLine() {
    Commandline commandLine = new Commandline();

    // build the command line from what we got the format is
    // ss Get VSS items [-G] [-H] [-I-] [-N] [-O] [-R] [-V] [-W] [-Y] [-?]
    // as specified in the SS.EXE help
    commandLine.setExecutable(getSSCommand());
    commandLine.createArgument().setValue(COMMAND_GET);

    if (getVsspath() == null) {
        throw new BuildException("vsspath attribute must be set!", getLocation());
    }
    commandLine.createArgument().setValue(getVsspath());

    // -GL
    commandLine.createArgument().setValue(getLocalpath());
    // -I- or -I-Y or -I-N
    commandLine.createArgument().setValue(getAutoresponse());
    // -O-
    commandLine.createArgument().setValue(getQuiet());
    // -R
    commandLine.createArgument().setValue(getRecursive());
    // -V
    commandLine.createArgument().setValue(getVersionDateLabel());
    // -W
    commandLine.createArgument().setValue(getWritable());
    // -Y
    commandLine.createArgument().setValue(getLogin());
    // -G
    commandLine.createArgument().setValue(getFileTimeStamp());
    // -GWS or -GWR
    commandLine.createArgument().setValue(getWritableFiles());

    return commandLine;
}
```

and ***`org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.vss.MSVSS`*** class:

```
/**
 * Gets the version string. Returns the first specified of version "-V1.0",
 * date "-Vd01.01.01", label "-Vlbuild1".
 * @return An empty string if a version, date and label are not set.
 */
protected String getVersionDateLabel() {
    String versionDateLabel = "";
    if (version != null) {
        versionDateLabel = FLAG_VERSION + version;
    } else if (date != null) {
        versionDateLabel = FLAG_VERSION_DATE + date;
    } else {
        // Use getShortLabel() so labels longer then 30 char are truncated
        // and the user is warned
        String shortLabel = getShortLabel();
        if (shortLabel != null && !shortLabel.equals("")) {
            versionDateLabel = FLAG_VERSION_LABEL + shortLabel;
        }
    }
    return versionDateLabel;
}
```

you should set *`date`* attribute of [`vssget`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/vss.html#vssget) task.

Try to set `date` attribute's value in different formats (`MM/dd/yy;hh:mma`, `mm/dd/yyyy;h:mma` or `dd.mm.yyyy`). 
[This article](http://brennan.offwhite.net/mtblog/archives/000282.html) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911426/get-all-files-from-vss-or-a-given-date) can help you to find the correct format.

The correct date time format, IMHO, depends on regional settings of VSS database.
This [issue post](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MPCHANGELOG-67) is about solving a similar problem.