# Visual Source Safe - Is there a way to get last version of the files in a code set that I checked in?

Tags: visual-sourcesafe

I am working on an old project where when I left off, I checked everying in and since then, other people have worked on the project. I was wondering if there is a way to get lastest version of the code set, but only be the files that I checked in last, not the current latest version.

I have been in the world of SVN as of late, so I am a bit rusty with VSS. I have searched the web and cannot seem to key in on what I could do to make this happen. I know you can do more from the command line with VSS that is closer to a database query, I am just not that savy. I will keep looking, but hopefully this is a no brainer for someone on here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Click the history button.
You can enter a date range or a user name (or neither for a complete history).

Comment: I know you can do that, and thank you very much for the reply. What I would really like to do is recursively grab the last file that I checked in for a specific project. What you stated will allow me to see all the files I checked in last, but I think I would still have to manually get that version. Unless I am missing something and I can do what I want from that dialog? I would like to automatically get the last version for the whole project of every file that I last touched and checked in. Thanks again for the response.

Comment: Try this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/911426/get-all-files-from-vss-for-a-given-date